# Basic Geometric Series Question

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Calculation of
$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{2n} z^{2n} $

The answer is

1. We note that the n-th summand has the form $(2z)^n$
   Denoting w = 2z The sum is sigma of 0 to n summand being $(w)^n$ 
   which can be transformed into 1/(1-w) Rewriting in closed form is $1/(1-2z)$

I don't understand the statement shouldn't you be transforming $w = z^2$
why do you change the form into $(2z)^n$??

Can please help me out? Thank you, sorry for the style

Comment: Do you mean the sum to be of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{2n}z^{2n}$ ?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on formatting equations.  Your post is very difficult to understand.  You appear to have lost the $2$ from the exponents.

Comment: It's what @MPW said

Answer (score 1):

Either the answer or the question is misstated.

If the question is right, then the series is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{2n}z^{2n} = 1 + 2^2z^2 + 2^4z^4 + 2^6z^6+\cdots$$
$$= 1+(2^2z^2)^1 +(2^2z^2)^2 + (2^2z^2)^3 + \cdots$$

This is a geometric series with ratio $r=2^2z^2$, so the sum is $$\frac{1}{1-r} = \boxed{\dfrac{1}{1-2^2z^2}}$$

If the question is really supposed to be to evaluate $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{n}z^{n}$$
then the series is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{n}z^{n} = 1 + 2^1z^1 + 2^2z^2 + 2^3z^3+\cdots$$
$$= 1+(2z)^1 +(2z)^2 + (2z)^3 + \cdots$$

which is a geometric series with ratio $r = 2z$, so the sum would be $$\frac{1}{1-r} = \boxed{\dfrac{1}{1-2z}}$$

Comment: It was the upper one. I guess the answer was wrong because what I got was the lower one and I was confused, what a bullcrap from prof.